# Changing Button Color

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the button with the words "Button Demo" to turn blue (or any other color) upon hovering over it, however, I can't seem to get it done. There is something wrong with the code, but where's the mistake and how do I correct it?

```
<body>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Button Factory <img src="/img/gearbutton.jpg" style="width:40px;height:40px"></h1>

    <button id="buttondemo">Button Demo</button>

    <script>
    $('#buttondemo').click(function(){location.href="button_demo.html";});
    </script>

    <script>
    $('#buttondemo').hover(function(){style="color:#0000FF";});
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#buttondemo').hover(function(){$(this).css('color','#0000FF');});
</script>
```

Try the above.
However, it might be better to do this using :hover in css

Css:

```
#buttondemo:hover{
  color:#0000FF;
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks! But is there a way to make it turn back to its original color after moving the mouse away?

Comment: Try hooking up a mouseout event that puts it back

Comment: It might be better to do this using css :hover though

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS solution:

```
#buttondemo:hover{color:red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eot8du06/1/